# What is the most proper way to handle last back click before closing an app

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, back-stack

I am trying to implement confirm message to exit from my app. I need this, because someone can accidentally click back button more than one time and this will close the app and in case of low memory it will be killed after that because now it is not in foreground.
I have tried different approaches, but some of them required a lot of checks, others doesn't work at all.
I have tried to use `onKeyDown` event, `onBackPressed` ...
The problem because I am working not with only with activities, but also with nested fragments (inside activities).
I need to handle the last on back pressed click before exit, so it means that all fragments of current activity have to be popped up from the stack, than activity has to be popped up also and that if this is not last activity do the same for the preceding activity until this is not last activity and all fragments are popped up in it.
How can I implement this ? I have tried to do this using backstack, but unfortunately haven't succeed.
Please suggest what is the best to handle such type of event. I guess that there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: You can show AlertDialog in `onBackPressed()` and call `finish()` method if yes is clicked. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html
To create AlertDialog use AlertDialog.Builder
Do not call super.onBackPressed() because it closes activity.

Comment: Now it doesn't matter what I have to do, I need just the to listen to the last click before exit.

Comment: Exit confirmation messages are discouraged. You are working around the problem it seems. Save your state correctly when the app is destroyed and restore it at startup.

Comment: I see that it is not good practice to confirm exit from android apps, but I am just contractor. And that is not my idea to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answers and suggestions.
I have reached the desired result by using fragment count in the stack.
As far as my Main Activity will be the first activity and the last before exit, I can override `onBackPressed` method inside it.
So solution is simple.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseSingleFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle(R.string.title_exit_message)
                    .setMessage(R.string.message_exit)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_text_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_text_no, null)
                    .show();

        } else {
            MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

So this will work only if your activity is last in Activity Stack , so you have to override it your launcher activity, not in some base activity class or other.

A little bit improved solution to my mind.

```
 package com.crosp.solutions.qrcodereader.dialogs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;

import com.crosp.solutions.qrcodereader.R;
import com.crosp.solutions.qrcodereader.constants.FragmentConstants;

/**
 * Created by crosp on 7/9/15.
 */
public class ConfirmationDialog extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    private OnConfirmDialogClickListener mOnConfirmDialogListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mOnConfirmDialogListener = (OnConfirmDialogClickListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            Log.e(getString(R.string.error_tag), "Activty has to implement " + OnConfirmDialogClickListener.class.getSimpleName() + " interface");
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_text_yes, this)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_text_no, this);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String message = getString(R.string.message_exit);
        String title = getString(R.string.title_exit_message);
        int iconId = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
        if (bundle != null) {
            String argumentMessage = bundle.getString(FragmentConstants.Arguments.DIALOG_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT);
            String argumentTitle = bundle.getString(FragmentConstants.Arguments.DIALOG_TITLE_ARGUMENT);
            int argumentIconId = bundle.getInt(FragmentConstants.Arguments.DIALOG_ICON_ID_ARGUMENT);
            message = argumentMessage != null ? argumentMessage : message;
            title = argumentTitle != null ? argumentTitle : title;
            iconId = argumentIconId != 0 ? argumentIconId : iconId;
        }
        builder.setIcon(iconId);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
            mOnConfirmDialogListener.onConfirmClick();
        } else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
            mOnConfirmDialogListener.onCancelClick();
        }
    }

    public interface OnConfirmDialogClickListener {
        void onConfirmClick();

        void onCancelClick();
    }
}
```

And in activity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseSingleFragmentActivity implements ExitConfirmDialogFactory.OnExitDialogClickListener {
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        if(mExitDialog==null) {
            arguments.putInt(FragmentConstants.Arguments.DIALOG_ICON_ID_ARGUMENT, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            arguments.putString(FragmentConstants.Arguments.DIALOG_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT, getString(R.string.message_exit));
            arguments.putString(FragmentConstants.Arguments.DIALOG_TITLE_ARGUMENT, getString(R.string.title_exit_message));
            DialogFragment exitDialog = new ConfirmationDialog();
            exitDialog.setArguments(arguments);
            mExitDialog = exitDialog;
        }
        mExitDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),FragmentConstants.Tags.EXIT_DIALOG_TAG);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfirmClick() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onCancelClick() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically override `onBackPressed`() in the **Main Activity** and avoid calling the parent `super.onBackPressed()` if the user selects "No" to exiting the app.

Code suggestion:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Exiting app?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // user really do want to exit
                MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }).create().show();
     // If negative, show a Fragment or do nothing
}
```

Comment: I have already tried something like this, the problem is that it will display message each time fragment is popped out the stack.  I need to handle fragments popups from the stack as well all activities because in case of multiple activities in back stack it will also ask user about exit but it will just returns back to the previous activity on the stack.

Comment: @CROSP, If you do this in the Main Activity, it will only trigger in the activity, not the fragment.

Comment: I understand, but I have nested fragments inside Activity on the stack, back button will trigger each time I click it, because for activity it is simple click , and I guess super.onBackPress removes fragment from the back stack, so this message will appear each time fragment is been popped up

Comment: @CROSP, Thanks for the clarification. I did not know that about the Back key. I guess this is different than other listeners because the key is always available, hence visible.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think you can use an integer to count your fragments, increase it on adding a new fragment and decrease on every back press. It may be like that:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() { 
if( fragCount > 0) {
    --fragCount;
    super.onBackPressed();
    return;
}

new     AlertDialog.Builder(this) .setTitle("Exiting app?") .setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { // user really do want to exit    
 MainActivity.super.onBackPressed(); } }).create().show();
 }
```

Note: Sorry for bad typing I am on phone.